# Idiom for a person who is above any question

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

I read somewhere a sentence which said about a political leader that he is the "holy **something**" whose actions cannot be questioned.

The context was to describe that even though this man does bad things, due to his power people are afraid to question his actions. I can not remember the correct idiom, so please help. If you know any similar idiom that can be used in such a context, that would also be great.

Comment: *Holy* would ordinarily be used only of a leader whose source of power is his religious status; is it possible that the word you saw or heard was *wholly* = "entirely"? Or is it possible that the phrase addressed the leader's statements, not the leader himself, calling them something like "Holy writ" or "Holy scripture"?

Comment: It may have been a faulty reference to "Holy Grail".

Comment: In my country, there are only nine such people: the supreme court justices. Which county's political leader said that?

Comment: Were they being referred to as the "holy pope"? With the idea that they're not the pope, but to imply a similar (alleged) inability to be wrong.

Comment: It was "Holier than though" as user181742 mentioned.

Comment: Please mark that as [your accepted answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333500/idiom-for-a-person-who-is-above-any-question/333522#333522).

Comment: "Holier than thou" definitely does **not** fit the definition in your question. Not even a little bit. People are not afraid to criticize people who are "holier than thou"; in fact, that attitude tends to provoke criticism.

Comment: Sysadmin, moderator, ...

Comment: OP - Do you realize that you accepted invalid answer? "Holier than thou" means a person who PRETENDS to be above questioning, but for everyone involved is obvious that  "Holier than thou" person is wrong.

Comment: _Above any question_? Well, that would be the guys on the upper floor of the Stack Exchange's data center building.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**is considered beyond reproach**

> **beyond reproach**  Blameless, faultless, as in Jean's conduct at school is beyond reproach. The phrase employs the verb to reproach in the sense of "censure or rebuke," a usage dating from the early 1500s.
>   — [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beyond+reproach)

> **reproach** — [...] reprochen "to rebuke, reproach," from Anglo-French repruchier, Old French reprochier **"upbraid, blame, accuse, speak ill of,"** [...]
>   — [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reproach)

**EDIT:**
Originally this answer was simply **beyond reproach** though, as commenters said, this implies subject is in fact perfect, hence added the prefix **"is considered"** as suggested by @jasper

Comment: Above reproach vs. Beyond reproach : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beyond+reproach%2Cabove+reproach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeyond%20reproach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabove%20reproach%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I think "beyond reproach" implies that the subject is in fact perfect.  That is not what is being asked here

Comment: No one is perfect (except those nine people ;). This is always a figure of speech.

Comment: The word *irreproachable* exists, too.

Comment: @Mazura A figure of speech, yes, but its connotation is positive as Andrey suggests. This would be a compliment; it wouldn't imply the person is guilty of much wrongdoing.

Comment: @jpmc26 But if you change *is* beyond reproach to *is considered* to be beyond reproach (or considers his own {x} to be beyond reproach) and it quickly turns into a highly critical claim.

Comment: @Jasper It would still carry the connotation that many think highly of them, which is also probably unintended. It certainly wouldn't suggest that most fear the person. So yes, highly critical, but it implies your opinion is uncommon, which isn't what the question describes.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree, it does have a bit of that connotation. However, it is a very flexible term and by changing the sentence structure or the context you can easily use the term to more exactly what you mean. If you're worried about the forced part, for example, you can make it "people are supposed to consider him beyond reproach" or "his words are to be considered beyond reproach"

Comment: "beyond reproach" is an idiom?

Comment: @kris The OP's question was tagged with phrase-requests and  idiom-requests.

Comment: I saw discussion in the above-the-law answer by @Rathony regarding whether that one is a phrase or a idiom, and I admit "is considered beyond reproach" is closer to a phrase that "above-the-law" is. I think the lines between phrases and idioms may be sometimes blurry however!

Comment: Almost any compliment can be made questionable with appropriate qualifiers or sarcastic tone of voice. But the basic meaning of this phrase is complimentary.

Answer (score 31):

[Above the law](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/above_the_law):

> (idiomatic) Exempt from the laws that apply to everyone else.

[Wiktionary]

Your example:

> The politician is **above the law** and people can't question his actions.

Comment: why the downvote? That's an idiom that applies to the definition given. +1

Comment: Definitely the best answer given the connotations that the OP is looking for.

Comment: Mandatory Southpark reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-jXe0x4YdM

Comment: I had wanted to mention this point too in my earlier comment, in fact: Start by seeing the definition of an idiom: "a group of words established by usage as having **a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words** (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light )." (Google) -- Helpful inclusion of "idiomatic expressions" is not wrong on the part of dictionaries.

Comment: @Kris That entirely depends on how you define an idiom. If you are a pedant, it might not be an idiom, I agree. But, for learners, they may not know what "above the law" implies. That's what the idiom dictionary is for.

Answer (score 29):

There's an idiom that involves religion and could apply to your case:

> **Sacred cow**

from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_cow_%28idiom%29) and [Collins](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sacred%20cow)

"**someone** or something that has been accepted or respected for a long time and **that people are afraid** or unwilling **to criticize** or question" (emphasis, mine)

With "Holy" there's *Holy Cow*, but that *does not apply* to your definition; it is just an exclamation to avoid blasphemy –from a Christian centric point of view– though it might be blasphemous for an Hindu.

Comment: I think this is probably what they were thinking of with the "holy" thing.

Comment: Tangentially there's Holier-than-thou for someone who thinks he's superior to others (but is not necessarily).

Answer (score 14):

You may say that the politician in question is an ***[untouchable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/untouchable)***:

> - a person who is beyond reproach as to honesty, diligence, etc.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Living in the US, I've never actually heard the phrase untouchable used in a positive way, only in documentaries talking about the Hindu caste.

Comment: @rw-nandemo - 1) OP is looking for an idiomatic expression which has a negative connotation by definition. 2) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Untouchables_(film)

Comment: "Untouchable" apparently originating from the law enforcement agents from the 30's and "untouchable" referring to a caste of Indian society are entirely separate words; the former has zero negative connotations and the latter is entirely negative.

Comment: I was under the impression that untouchable law enforcement agents are agents that can't be bought. Their actions can certainly be questioned, but one would know that any mistakes or shortcomings wouldn't be due to corruption by criminals...

Comment: I've always distinguished the two by using the caste term only as a noun, and the other only as an adjective (the movie based on the book by Ness has it coined from an adjective into the proper noun).  the usage this answer refers to has been stretched (in entertainment media at least) to include protection/defense against any kind of punishment or reprisal, legally *or* criminally speaking - basically synonymous with the non-literal use of "bulletproof".

Answer (score 11):

The phrase that is used to describe the Catholic pope is **infallible**.

> incapable of making mistakes or being wrong.

> not fallible; exempt from liability to error, as persons, their judgment, or pronouncements

This may be the word that you're looking for.

Comment: You should link to the origins of your quotes.

Answer (score 9):

Did you mean "[Holier-than-thou](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254911/what-would-you-call-a-person-who-is-self-righteous-brags-about-her-his-moral-va/254929#254929)"?

- marked by an air of superior piety or morality

  - having or showing the annoying attitude of people who believe that they are morally better than other people. ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holier-than-thou))
  - excessively or hypocritically pious ([Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/holier-than-thou))

Comment: @bhats that idiom does not mean what you put in your definition: holier than thou is someone who thinks he's beyond reproach, but it has nothing to do with his effective power.

Comment: @P.Obertelli It also means that the subject is prone to criticizing others for their shortcomings, while ignoring his own. Often associated with hypocracy.

Comment: @jpmc26: Or hypocrisy. :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect, holier-than-thou is attitude of someone who thinks he's morally above his surroundings and expresses this believe in an annoying manner.

Comment: Who is the *thou* in "holier than thou"? Have a good look at the etymology and usage of the phrase. This is diametrically opposite to what's needed.

Answer (score 7):

For an idiom and not a literal word or phrase, consider *Caesar's wife*.

[Caesar's wife must be above suspicion](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Caesar's+wife+must+be+above+suspicion) (TFD-Idioms)

> Prov. **The associates of public figures must not even be suspected of wrongdoing**.
>   Jill: I don't think the mayor is trustworthy; his brother was charged with embezzlement. Jane: But the charges were never proved. Jill: That doesn't matter. Caesar's wife must be above suspicion. When the newspapers reported the rumor that the lieutenant governor had failed to pay his taxes, the governor forced him to resign, saying, "Caesar's wife must be above suspicion."
>   (emphasis added)

Answer (score 6):

Another term for "above any question" is **unassailable**:

> not able to be doubted, attacked, or questioned

[[Merriam-Webster]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassailable)

> Due to his influence, the corrupt politician was *unassailable*.

Comment: I think "unassailable" has a slightly different connotation. I find it mostly  used to mean "something that is hard to refute or reject", like "his logic was unassailable".

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is:
"wholly beyond reproach"
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beyond+reproach

Answer (score 2):

If the reference was definitely "holy" something, it may have been
**holy icon**

using the following meaning of **[icon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/icon)**

> a famous person or thing that represents something of importance

[or](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/icon)

> a person who is very successful and admired

[Example](https://www.rt.com/politics/journalist-eco-campaigner-beating-died-691/):

> “For me, as the head of the Journalists’ Union, he is a holy icon.”

Answer (score 1):

> holy father

the holy father is a common name for the pope, whose words are considered infallible (with caveats) in the catholic faith. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility)

> holy see

the holy see is one of the names for the vatican, which rules over the entire catholic church. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican)

obviously, both these terms are more nuanced than my quick soundbites convey. as such, they should not be considered theological definitions, but rather guidelines for vernacular metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is accepted completely is said to be "beyond question." It is not about anything that hasn't been already discussed and resolved.