# The word for discrimination against people from other regions within a country?

Tags: single-word-requests, racism

I wonder if "racism" can be used to refer to discrimination against people from other regions within the same country. [According to the Oxford dictionary, the definition of "racism" is](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/racism):

> Prejudice, discrimination, or antagonism directed against someone of a **different race** based on the belief that one's own race is superior.

So it is up to the definition of "race".

Now, [the definition of "race" is](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/race):

> Each of the major divisions of humankind, having distinct **physical** characteristics.

However, people from other regions usually don't have different **physical** characteristics.

Is there any such word to refer to discrimination against people who were born and/or grew up in other regions within the same country?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396294/word-for-prejudice-against-rural-people?rq=1

Comment: It’s worth noting that “racism” is used in many contexts that don’t always relate to *race* (which is a vague concept to begin with), and is often an umbrella term encompassing xenophobia, antisemitism and islamophobia, amongst others.

Comment: Usually it is helpful to provide an example sentence showing how the word will be used.  (I think *provincialism* is such a slam dunk, though, that it's not so critical in this case.)

Comment: *"...based on the belief that one's own race is superior."* And what about the belief that the other race is superior?

Comment: The answers are addressing a different understanding of the question to mine, so for clarity: do you want a term for discrimination against everyone who isn't from my region ("We're better than everyone else") or for discrimination against people who are from one or more specific regions other than my own ("People from there are inbreds")?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sectarianism is a technically valid word for describing it. The Wikipedia article on [sectarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectarianism) mentions differences in regions within a country as an example of the phenomenon:

> Sectarianism is a form of bigotry, discrimination, or hatred arising
>   from attaching relations of inferiority and superiority to differences
>   between subdivisions within a group. Common examples are denominations
>   of a religion, ethnic identity, class, or **region for citizens of a
>   state** and factions of a political movement.

However, the word is most commonly used for differences between two groups within the same religion.

Comment: Good answer. Then this would be better as a compound word, such as "regional sectarianism".

Answer (score 34):

*[Provincialism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/provincialism)* seems appropriate. Wikipedia equates *parochialism* but the concept of parish might not translate so well around the world.

The second definition from Oxford Dictionaries fits well:

> Concern for one's own area or region at the expense of national or supranational unity.

Comment: That was going to my choice as well. +1

Comment: This sounds a good word but I wonder if this can be used for people in the capital area. [According to Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/provincialism): *The way of life characteristic of the regions **outside the capital city of a country**, especially when regarded as unsophisticated or narrow-minded.*

Comment: @Blaszard The folks in the city center surely wouldn't think so, but OD's definitions 1.1 and 2. at your link would apply to them, as well: *Narrow-mindedness, insularity, or lack of sophistication. . . . Concern for one's own area or region at the expense of national or supranational unity.* I'm not 100% convinced that provincialism necessarily includes discriminating against folks from other areas *once they have come to your region*, but I think it's pretty close.

Comment: Adam, this is exactly the right word in my opinion but I can't upvote such a bare bones answer.

Comment: Provincialism is often used to refer to the opinions and habits of people from small towns, as opposed to the capital and other large cities. I think this makes it less suitable for the OP's use case.

Comment: Good job adding a definition. I also added the name of your source, and quote formatting; feel free to modify that edit as desired.

Comment: @1006a Thanks for the edit, looks good.

Answer (score 21):

***chauvinism***, [Merriam-Webster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405918/the-word-for-discrimination-against-people-from-other-regions-within-a-country)

> undue partiality or attachment to a group or place to which one
>   belongs or has belonged •regional chauvinism

We all know what a *male chauvinist* is, but chauvinism or chauvinist can be used in almost any context.

For example, an MIT student might say:

> I am unabashedly a MIT chauvinist, especially when it comes to Harvard
>   -- that playboy's school down the road.

You can have New York City chauvinists, Southern chauvinists...you name it; although chauvinist will sound peculiar in some contexts, the meaning will be clear.

Origin:  See [Nicolas Chauvin, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Chauvin):

> Nicolas Chauvin (French: is a legendary, possibly apocryphal French
>   soldier and patriot who is supposed to have served in the First Army
>   of the French Republic and subsequently in La Grande Armée of
>   Napoleon. His name is the eponym of chauvinism, originally a term for
>   excessive nationalistic fervor, but later used to refer to any form of
>   bigotry or bias (e.g., male chauvinism).

Comment: While certainly a valid answer, I would caution against using this day-to-day on account of the common interchangeability of "chauvinist" and "male chauvinist."

Answer (score 19):

This could also be termed Tribalism.

Definition of tribalism, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tribalism)

> 1 :  tribal consciousness and loyalty; *especially* :  exaltation of the tribe above other groups
>
> 2 :  strong in-group loyalty

Answer (score 16):

I would try ***xenophobia***: in its broad sense means hatred of foreigners ( xenos ) in Greek. From a historical point of view, when the term xenos was coined they were no nations like we know them now so a village across the valley was or could be a place of xenoi people.

**Xenophobia**, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophobia)

> fear and hatred of strangers or foreigners or of anything that is
>   strange or foreign

Comment: Xenophobia doesn't specifically mean 'hate of foreigners', but strangers, outsiders or guests.
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/xeno-

Answer (score 10):

You could call it **regionism**.

You're right about *racism*: it is properly confined to discriminating by race, and the concept of human races is an 18th-century European construct based on different physical characteristics of the body, especially of the head, face, and skin. The traditional four races are black, white, red, and yellow. It has little basis in genetics and is considered obsolete in science. It is thought better by some to drop the term entirely in favour of *discrimination*; but, if one must use it, it is advised to stick with the traditional division, in which e.g. the average person in Iraq or India belongs to the white race irrespective of skin colour. (That's the kind of unappealing debate you may get into when you use the word *racism*.)

Comment: Although [regionalism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regionalism) doesn't necessarily mean prejudice; it can simply mean noting or promoting regional differences, specialties, or idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Davo but it does have a very bad connotation. Describing differences between races will always be seen as racist, no matter how factual

Comment: regionism? regionalism?

Comment: @Davo Nationalism _also_ technically doesn't imply prejudice, but that's usually how it works out with nationalists.

Comment: "Regionism" needs a citation, unless you're proposing it as a neologism. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regionalism) just gives it as a synonym for "regionalism" which doesn't have discriminatory meanings.

Answer (score 1):

You already have some good answers. Nevertheless consider the following words:

> [Localism](http://localism)
>
> *affection or partiality for a particular place :  [sectionalism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sectionalism)*
>
> **EDIT**:  Jack Aidley called to my attention that [Localism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/localism) has a different 
>   meaning in UK English. And I quote ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/localism)):
>
> *the idea that people should have control over what happens in their*
>   *local area, that local businesses should be supported, and that*
>   *differences between places should be respected*

---

> [Sectionalism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sectionalism)
>
> *an exaggerated devotion to the interests of a region*
>
> **NOTE**: This is different from [sectarism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sectarism).

In some contexts you might also consider:

> [Nativism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nativist)
>
> ***1:***  a policy of favoring native inhabitants as opposed to immigrants
>
> ***2:***  the revival or perpetuation of an indigenous culture especially in
>   *opposition to acculturation*

Comment: Localism is, however, usually used in political discourse for having decisions made at the local level rather than preferential treatment of locals - at least in the UK.

Comment: @JackAidley Indeed it seems the Cambridge Dictionary gives the word [Localism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/localism) a different meaning. I'll edit the answer to add a warning about this. Thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

I know Italian is not what you're looking for, but google and have a read on "campanilismo". This is a very well founded phenomenon in Italy.

Comment: So why not provide the [link](https://ilcampanilismo.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/the-concept-of-campanilismo/), the [best](https://www.britannica.com/topic/campanilismo) one that is the most accurate and [pertinent](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/campanilismo). Why propose an answer in a completely different language and tell a user to Google it? Yes, "campanilismo" is perfect in Italian where it is the norm to have rivalries between neighbouring villages and towns,  let alone regions.

Comment: I think this is relevant. Italy has a longer history of internal divisions than most countries of the Anglosphere, hence the need for a term to describe regional hostility.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using terms such as biased, prejudiced, or discrimination instead of racism when indicating negativity aimed at someone due to their religious beliefs. Chauvinism and racism have come to mean very specific things and would make things more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This probably comes from German, but here in Slovenia we also use the term
"local patriot"/(ism)", which is quite descriptive in any language (but it does have a negative connotation).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is a word that conveys exactly what you want, probably because the reality you want to express is rare in the English speaking world. You could use "prejudice", although that is a very general term. Extreme prejudice of the kind that leads to political discrimination,  typically coalesces around differences of race, religion or language. We have words for each of these things.

The only exception I can think of is the prejudice that American northerners express towards southerners -- but since the northerners have no moral qualms about this, no one has thought to come up with a word for "despising a group of people previously defeated in a civil war".

In general, where two groups of people have race, language, religion, citizenship and ideology in common, animosity due to regional differences can usually be overcome through the recognition of common ground and shared interests. Mutual hatred does not occur and the word you seek is not needed.

Comment: "*the reality you want to express is rare in the English speaking world*" - really??! I can think of many examples on lots of scales (from village vs village to nation vs nation) in the UK, and I find it hard to believe that the same isn't true to some extent in every country large enough to have regions. Human nature doesn't vary quite that much,

Comment: regional animosities exist, but words like racism and islamophobia are fairly new and reflect a political campaign to change people's group identities. The XIXth century English did not see their contempt for Irish Catholics as anything other than a sign of good judgment on their part, for example.