# Is there a single word meaning 'a person who loves to represent their city'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, nouns

A person who is especially proud to be from a particular city, and puts down others from opposing cities. They rep their city as if it's a sports team. This is especially true in the US.

Could you please suggest a single word one could use to describe such a person well (not a gross hypernym like 'supporter')?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I have to assume this question is looking for a word and have edited accordingly. See also [The word for discrimination against people from other regions within a country?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/405918/191178)

Comment: In the UK, we have City fans, but that's different.

Comment: This single word thing sometimes beggars belief...

Comment: The duplicate gives 'boosterism' which leads directly to 'booster'. Also 'localist.'

Comment: @Lambie There are so many single words for things that you wouldn't expect that you would expect there to be a single word for anything. But that's just not how it works.

Comment: @Mitch That doesn't make much sense....

Comment: @Lambie "There are so many (single words (for things that (you wouldn't expect))) that ((you would expect) there to be (a single word for anything))"

Comment: @Mitch Like they say in the British Parliament: hear, hear, hear

Answer (score 1):

*Booster* does fall into the hypernym category, but it collocates with cities and municipalities. If you don't find a single word, perhaps *city-booster*.

**booster** (n.)

> One that boosts: such as an enthusiastic supporter
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/booster)

> US
> A person who enthusiastically supports or promotes something (=
> tells people how good it is):
>
> *I don't want to come across as a **booster** for any particular product.*
>
> *The mayor and town **boosters** hope the new ballpark will be a catalyst for development.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/booster)

> A **booster** is someone who supports a sports team, organization,
> person, or place very enthusiastically.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/booster)

---

> In the local newspaper, the *Corona Daily Independent*, **city
> boosters** boasted that great golf tournaments held at the Parkridge
> would accrue national and international recognition for their citrus
> belt community and generate publicity benefits that would attract
> tourists.
> [Alison Jefferson; *Living the California Dream*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0k3BDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&dq=booster%20for%20the%20city&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd1eXm-omCAxWWFlkFHenaC9g4FBDoAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=booster%20for%20the%20city&f=false) (2020)

> On the general brokers side, the typical realtor was an enthusiastic
> **booster** of urban planning and land-use regulation, mostly beginning around 1914 and particularly during the early 1020s.
> [Marc
> Weiss; *The Rise of the Community Builders*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXjddnZYyLYC&pg=PA49&dq=enthusiastic%20booster&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj66rTz_YmCAxVWFFkFHQO7CNA4FBDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=enthusiastic%20booster&f=false) (2002)

> The River and Harbor Convention was a classic **city-boosting** event. Chicago **boosters** inserted into the convention's printed proceedings a twenty-page statistical appendix that celebrated the city's development.
> ... The city's **boosters** had lobbied strenuously to convince
> eastern organizers to choose Chicago for the convention site.
> [Robin
> Einhorn; *Property Rules: Political Economy in Chicago, 1833-1872*](https://books.google.com/books?id=M6CUhCQtOSMC&pg=PA63&dq=these%20boosters%20%20city&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2tcHj_omCAxXPK1kFHQiJAHcQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=these%20boosters%20%20city&f=false)
> (1991)

Comment: It should be emphasised that using this term in this sense will be readily understood only by the speakers of American English. Even among them, it may be perceived as somewhat old-fashioned. How well it fits what the OP had in mind depends on what precisely she meant by 'rep' in 'they rep their city'.